# How to use file in-memory?

Tags: python, file, python-3.8, virtual-file

The following code currently saves the file to disk. Can I save it to memory instead?

```
def synthesize(iam_token, text):
    url = 'https://example.com/tts:synthesize'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + iam_token,
    }

    data = {
        'text': text
    }

    with requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, stream=True) as resp:
        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
            yield chunk


with open('/tmp/tts.ogg', 'wb') as f:
    for audio_content in synthesize(iam_token, text):
        f.write(audio_content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the BytesIO object [from the io package.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o)

```
import io

buffer = io.BytesIO()
for audio_content in sythesize(iam_token,text):
    buffer.write(audio_content)
```